# Verified $(\ln x)^{\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine the derivative of $(\ln x)^{\cos x}$

Can anyone verified my answer:

$(\ln x)^{\cos x}(-\sin x\ln (\ln x)+\frac{\cos x}{x\ln x})$

Or do I have too many $x$'s in my answer?

Comment: [Looks good](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+ln%28x%29^cos%28x%29).

Comment: There is no such thing as too many $x$'s. You have the right number, in the right positions.

Comment: Why the downvotes? In any event, how about http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%28ln%28x%29^{cos%28x%29}%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y = ( \ln x)^{\cos x } \implies \ln y = \cos x \ln (\ln x) $. Hence

$$ \frac{y'}{y} = - \sin x \ln (\ln x) +  \frac{\cos x}{ x \ln x } $$

Therefore, $$y' = (\ln x)^{\cos x} (- \sin x \ln (\ln x) +  \frac{\cos x}{ x \ln x })  $$